# Showing a linear transformation is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

$T$ is a linear transformation from Banach space $X$ onto Banach space $Y$ such that $||Tx|| \geq \frac{1}{2020} ||x||$. I have to show that $T$ is bounded.

Attempted Proof:
From the given condition, it is easy to see that $Tx = 0$ implies that $x = 0$. Hence $T$ is injective and $T^{-1}$ exists. Therefore, for $y \in Y$, $\frac{1}{2020}||T^{-1}y||\leq||y||$, and hence $||T^{-1}y||\leq2020||y||$. Thus $T^{-1}$ is bounded. Now, we use Open Mapping Theorem to conclude that $T^{-1}$ is an open map and hence $T$ is continuous. Is there any problem with the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine proof. There are no problems with your proof. You should include that $T(X)=Y$, since $T$ is onto.